# Guitar held flat? how is this way of guitar playing called?

Tags: guitar

The boy on the right keeps the Guitar in a different way than usual. I wonder how you call this style.

Comment: I just googled using your search terms. First result is "lap style"

Comment: @DoktorMayhem  - exactly what I was about to comment!

Comment: Emmett’s playing slide on a dobro. It looks like it has a square neck and super-high action. This guitar would not be playable in traditional guitar style: it’s specifically made and set up for lap slide. Another search term is “lap steel”

Comment: Lap guitar.....

Comment: @Tim and DoktorMayhem: this not true! If I google with my terms I can‘t find an answer. But I‘m quite proud about my English progression as  I obviously used  the correct terms. Can you tell me what exactly you have googled?

Comment: Can you say where in that video we could see this boy?  I can't bear to listen to it, and watching for five minutes with the sound muted seems like a waste of five minutes.

Comment: haha I'll tell you the seconds: you can see him at sec. 50 ... I agree, I can't bear this voices too. ;) but the question seems to be answered!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The guitar being played "lap style" standing up is unique type of guitar commonly referred to as a resonator, or more commonly a Dobro. They are naturally loud and employ open tuning which allows them to be played using a metal bar. The action is usually set quite high and there is no effort to actually fret the note by pushing the strings down. Instead the "bar" acts as a movable fret. The guitar is held in the flat position in order to access the strings from the top instead of the front. Personally, I liken it to an acoustic version of an electric steel guitar, although I recognize a number of differences. The sound of this instrument immediately catches your attention when you hear it. It is uniquely American, but was developed by European immigrants to the U.S.  It's history is approximately 100 years old.

Comment: "was developed by European immigrants to the U.S.": do you have more information about that?

Comment: @phoog- you can find what you want to know by googling "John Dopyera". Wikipedia has the information you are probably looking for. I hope that helps you.